# scale can't recognize parameter in function with R

Tags: r, function

I'm really getting a lot of help in this community. I would really appreciate for all your help.

I'm making `function`. In `function` arguments, there is `scale`, which standardize the values.

However, when parameter get into `scale`, the `function` can't recognize the parameter.

```
set.seed(1000)
a<-rnorm(10)
b<-rnorm(10)
test<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

fun<-function(i,j,k){
  x<-
    test%>%dplyr::select(i,j)%>%
    dplyr::mutate(i=scale(i),
                  j=scale(j))
  return(x)
}
fun(i="a",j="b")

 Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I tried several approaches, but it all failed.

1. At first, I did it with `dplyr`. After the error, I changed it with basic function. It failed.
2. I put the double parenthesis, `{{}}`, around object. It failed.
3. I put the `as.formula`. It recognized the parameter, but it recognized it as independent object, not in original dataframe.

   Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]) : 
         object 'a' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass quoted columns we can use `mutate_at` in the function.

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(test, i, j) {
   test %>% mutate_at(vars(i, j), scale)
}
fun(test, "a", "b")

#         a      b
#1  -0.1673 -0.701
#2  -1.2571 -0.152
#3   0.5308  0.714
#4   1.3886  0.403
#5  -0.6559 -1.154
#6  -0.0809  0.776
#7  -0.2105  0.757
#8   1.5038  0.590
#9   0.4453 -2.065
#10 -1.4969  0.832
```

Comment: Really thanks! May I ask you one more question? I had same problem in 'arrange' fuction. It can't recognized parameter in it. "Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 5" appeared. Is there a solution?

Comment: @ESKim Yes, if you have string names of the column all the `_at` variants of `dplyr` would be helpful.

Comment: Hmm... However, with 'mutate_at', I can't create new variable, like mutate(new_variable=~). Is there a way to create new variable?

Comment: @ESKim Yes, put this in the function `test %>% mutate_at(vars(i, j), list(new = ~scale(.)))`

Answer (score 1):

If we are passing as unquoted, then one option is

```
fun <- function(test, i, j) {
   i1 <- rlang::quo_name(enquo(i))
   j1 <- rlang::quo_name(enquo(j))
   test %>% 
       mutate(!! i1:= scale({{i}}),
                   !! j1 := scale({{j}}))
}
fun(test, a, b)
#           a          b
#1  -0.16730753 -0.7009831
#2  -1.25711119 -0.1524233
#3   0.53081842  0.7139501
#4   1.38860927  0.4034140
#5  -0.65591381 -1.1542672
#6  -0.08086494  0.7763465
#7  -0.21045016  0.7571458
#8   1.50383307  0.5903152
#9   0.44531788 -2.0650886
#10 -1.49693102  0.8315905
```